# Can we count the Wordpress Loop

Tags: php, loop

Can we count the WordPress loop and store it in a variable?

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php $post_id = get_the_ID(); ?>
    <?php get_template_part('content','home'); ?>
       some code to be executed
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

what I want is that for every 5 posts fetched ceratin code should be executed(example newsletter) → That means within the loop for every 5h, 10th, 15th, ____________ infinite posts(5n, n>=1) the code should be executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$wp_query->current_post` is the build-in loop counter, starting with 0 zero for the first post in the loop.

so the line `some code to be executed` could translate to:

`<?php if( $wp_query->current_post > 0 && $wp_query->current_post % 5 == 0 ) { ?>
      some code to be executed
<?php } ?>`

Comment: sir, it worked, but can you help me in explaining this part → `current_post % 5 == 0`

Comment: It’s checking if the remainder of `current_post` divided by `5` is `0`.

Comment: OK! Thanks. It is a kind of pure maths but in coding form. The maths that we do in GRE or GMAT.

Answer (score 1):

PLease check this code snippet

```
 <?php  $i=0; 
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php $post_id = get_the_ID(); ?>
    if($i%5 == 0)
    {\\code to be executed}
    <?php get_template_part('content','home'); ?>
       some code to be executed
<?php $i++;endwhile;  ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```